# apache2 not running after graceful restart

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

Today my apache instance was automatically restarted gracefully by some cron job I guess, afterwards it was not running. The apache error log file shows:

```
[Fri Jun 03 06:25:04.379685 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8256] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/access_compat.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so: undefined symbol: ap_get_useragent_host
```

After manually starting it via

```
service apache2 start
```

it worked as expected.

I already disabled unattended security updates on this Ubuntu 14.04 machine because I had a similar issue last week where it printed

```
[Thu May 26 06:27:29.737707 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1487] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: symbol __strtold_nan, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

Is this some kind of race condition? Why is it not able to load the modules some times?

**UPDATE**

The line mentioned in the error looks like

```
LoadModule access_compat_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

so there is no syntax error in that line and I did not change anything to get it running again, just start apache again.

Comment: Did you actually examine the syntax errors it reports? Was it truly a malformed config?

Comment: I added the config file line that was mentioned in the error

Answer (score 3):

Thomas, I'd be interested to know if you found a solution to your issue. This bug affected me this morning. It is triggered any time Apache does a graceful reload, ironically. Yet running apache2 restart to restart the server works without issue. The graceful reload that I encountered was part of the post process of the log rotation script for apache (/etc/logrotate.d/apache2). The graceful reload is done here to release old log files so that they no longer consume disk space. I temporarily modified this in my job to use a restart instead of reload, thus avoiding the issue.

The error message in the log is pointing to the mod_access_compat module as being the problem, this being a core module I can't really do without it. So I went about researching and comparing differences. This issue only affected me once I upgraded from 2.4.16 to 2.4.20 (and 2.4.23 on another server). It appears that there's a change in 2.4.19 that suggests all modules use ap_get_useragent_host instead of the old ap_get_remote_host function to get remote IP of the visitor. I decided to download the latest source (2.4.23) and change this line in mod_access_compat.c (line 279) back to what it was previously in the older version: remotehost = ap_get_remote_host(r->connection, r->per_dir_config, REMOTE_DOUBLE_REV, &remotehost_is_ip);

Once I recompiled apache, I copied the new mod_access_compat.so into my modules folder replacing the shipped one. I've since been able to restart and reload gracefully without any trouble. Though I haven't moved this update into my production server yet, I will after hours.

This is obviously not a long-term solution, but it solved my problem until the Apache devs fix it properly. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Your mileage may vary, good luck!

**UPDATE**
I compiled my findings and submitted a bug report to the Apache devs. They suggested the server needed a full stop and start because some components were still in memory after the upgrade. I tested again and the graceful reload worked fine -- without replacing the module -- on the production servers. So, apparently this is a one-time bite you bug within the actual upgrade process because it should stop/start instead of restart the server. For anyone else who may experience this; just stop the server and start it again.

Here's the bug report I filed (I expect it to be marked as a non-bug really): https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59842

Comment: just encountered this problem in Ubuntu 18.04, with Apache 2.4.38